# Move from Custom EditText to another Custom EditText when Soft Keyboard Next is clicked on Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've searched a lot of threads and nothing resolved my problem.
How can I go to another field by clicking "next button" on keyboard in that condition?

I've got "FieldValidLayout" with TextViews and "CustomEditText". After next button clicked on keyboard i would like to go to the "CustomEditText" in next "FieldValidLayout".

Comment: try `android:singleLine="true"`

Answer (score 0):

you can directly add in xml

```
 android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

or if you want more functions then

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
//add your code 
}
```

Comment: I can't, it doesn't works. Probably focusing next textview in my parent FieldValidLayout